# How can I render a template with Django REST framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

How can I render a template with Django REST framework? When I try to run this code I am getting this error: `405 Method Not Allowed`. In my  terminal I see: `"GET /report/create/ HTTP/1.1" 405 22`.

How can I solve this error? I want to make a POST request with a JSON form.

views.py:

```
from rest_framework.renderers import TemplateHTMLRenderer, JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.generics import (CreateAPIView)
from .serializer import ArticleSerializer
from .models import Article

class ArticleCreateView(CreateAPIView):
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer, TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'create.html'
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and add a `get` method that returns the serializer. Similar to [this example](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/#rendering-forms).

```
class ArticleCreateView(CreateAPIView):
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer, TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'create.html'
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

    def get(self, request, pk):
        serializer = ArticleSerializer()
        return Response({'serializer': serializer})
```

Comment: when i use this code i am getting error `'str' object has no attribute 'data'`.

Comment: if i add this `data=request.data` then error showing (When a serializer is passed a `data` keyword argument you must call `.is_valid()` before attempting to access the serialized `.data` representation.You should either call `.is_valid()` first, or access `.initial_data` instead.)